# How to remove an element from a list during a loop iteration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When all conditions are met, the virtual method "onCollisionEnter" is executed, in which I delete the element.

list declaration:
`std::list<GameObject*> m_game_object_list;`

How to add an element to the list:

```
void Engine::Scene::createGameObjectWithUUID(UUID uuid, GameObject& object)
{
    object.addComponent<IDComponent>(uuid);
    object.addComponent<Transform>();
    object.addComponent<RectangleDrawable>();

    m_game_object_list.push_back(&object);
}
```

How the removal occurs:

```
void Engine::Scene::destroyGameObject(GameObject gameobject)
{
    auto uuid = gameobject.getUUID();
    for (auto j = m_game_object_list.begin(); j != m_game_object_list.end();)
    {
        if ((*j)->getUUID() == uuid)
        {
            delete* j;
            j = m_game_object_list.erase(j);
        }
        else
            ++j;
    }
}
```

The error occurs in this section of code:
Briefly: the item variable has memory address 0xdddddddddddddddd.

```
void Engine::Scene::update()
{
    {
        auto view = m_game_objects.view<Engine::RigidBody>();
        for (auto i : view)
        {
            GameObject game_object_1 = { i, this };
            auto& rigid_body_1 = game_object_1.getComponent<RigidBody>();
            auto& transform_1 = game_object_1.getComponent<Transform>();
            auto& box_collider_1 = game_object_1.getComponent<BoxCollider>();

            for (auto j : view)
            {
                GameObject game_object_2 = { j, this };
                auto& rigid_body_2 = game_object_2.getComponent<RigidBody>();
                auto& transform_2 = game_object_2.getComponent<Transform>();
                auto& box_collider_2 = game_object_2.getComponent<BoxCollider>();

                if (game_object_1.getUUID() != game_object_2.getUUID() &&
                    (rigid_body_1.type != RigidBody::BodyType::Static || rigid_body_2.type != RigidBody::BodyType::Static))
                {
                    float x_offset_1 = box_collider_1.size.x / 2;
                    float y_offset_1 = box_collider_1.size.y / 2;

                    float x_offset_2 = box_collider_2.size.x / 2;
                    float y_offset_2 = box_collider_2.size.y / 2;

                    if (transform_1.position.x - x_offset_1 <= transform_2.position.x + x_offset_2 &&
                        transform_1.position.y - y_offset_1 <= transform_2.position.y + y_offset_2 &&
                        transform_1.position.x + x_offset_1 >= transform_2.position.x - x_offset_2 &&
                        transform_1.position.y + y_offset_1 >= transform_2.position.y - y_offset_2  )
                    {
                        for (auto item : m_game_object_list)
                        {
                            for (auto item2 : m_game_object_list)
                            {
                                if (item->getUUID() == game_object_1.getUUID() &&
                                    item2->getUUID() == game_object_2.getUUID())
                                {
                                    item->onCollisionEnter(*item2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    {
        for (auto& i : m_game_object_list)
        {
            i->update();
        }
    }
    
    renderScene();
}
```

How can I improve my code to be able to remove elements during loop iterations?

I tried using 2 additional lists, but this introduced additional problems.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: With RAII, you don't have to manually call `delete`, and so a simple erase-remove idiom do the job.

Comment: Why do you store pointers in `m_game_object_list` instead of item objects?

Comment: ^[RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/4581301)!!! See if you can dial back the pointer use and let the container directly hold the object. It's usually faster, and the code becomes borderline brainless.

Comment: @273, I need to store a pointer to an object because I'm calling virtual functions elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Then why not use a smarter pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @Peter, By changing to smart pointers, objects on the stage stopped moving and reacting to collisions.
`std::list<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> m_game_object_list;`

Answer (score 0):

You need store somewhere a pointer to an object to be removed, then remove the object from the container using the iterator on it, and only then call **delete** operator on the pointer you previously preserved

In your code the fixed version of the method **Engine::Scene::destroyGameObject** would be something like this:

```
void Engine::Scene::destroyGameObject(GameObject gameobject)
{
    auto uuid = gameobject.getUUID();
    for (auto j = m_game_object_list.begin(); j != m_game_object_list.end();)
    {
        if ((*j)->getUUID() == uuid)
        {
            auto *pobj = *j;
            j = m_game_object_list.erase(j);
            delete pobj;
        }
        else
            ++j;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the other hand we actually do not know how a deletable object really collaborates with its container, which actually might be either non-intrusive or intrusive